# How to form callback url into query string in react hooks

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, callback, react-router

Where is a callback URL from a payment system, with this callback url I can get the transaction id and confirm if the payment is successful or not. I need to form this URL with a landing page on react

t

```
http://localhost:8081/confirmPayment/trans_202012201871?trxref=trans_202012201871&reference=trans_202012201871
```

So I have created a component from which I could get the trans id

This is the route I am trying to match with the callback URL from the payment company

```
<Route exact path="/confirmPayment/:ref?/:=trxref/:&=reference" component={ConfirmPaystackPayment} />
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Describe path as `/confirmPayment/:ref`

```
<Route exact path="/confirmPayment/:ref" component={ConfirmPaystackPayment} />
```

And to access `query params` in `ConfirmPaystackPayment` component use a trick [like this](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)